# Json Serialization in Unity - NullReferenceException : Object reference not set to an instance of an object

Tags: c#, json, unity-game-engine

I created several custom classes to read a json file in Unity.

**Fruits.cs**

```
[System.Serializable]
public class Fruits 
{
    public Apple[] apples;
}
```

**Apple.cs**

```
[System.Serializable]
public class Apple 
{
    public string appleName;
}
```

**MyClass.cs**

```
public class MyClass : MonoBehaviour{

private Fruits fruits;

public void classSetup(){
    StartCoroutine(JsonReader());     
    String appleName = fruits.apples[0].appleName;   -------> this is the line trigger the exception. 
    Debug.Log(appleName); 
}

Ienumerator JsonReader(){
   .........unrelated codes hidden...............
   if (Url.Contains(":/") || Url.Contains("://") || Url.Contains(":///"))
        {
            UnityWebRequest www = UnityWebRequest.Get(Url);
            yield return www.SendWebRequest();
            JsonText = www.downloadHandler.text;
        }

        fruits = JsonUtility.FromJson<Fruits>(JsonText);

}
}
```

The JsonReader (IEnumerator I created) works fine as the Debug.Log print out the appleName I expect but the line "String appleName ....." trigger an exception (NullReferenceException : Object reference not set to an instance of an object.)

I read posts about how to fix null exception, but was not able to find help on how to do that for a custom serialization class. Simply doing fruits = new Fruits() does not work. I suspect that's because I didn't instantiate the fields. But what if I have a lot of fields in Fruits class? And what if I can't just do "fruits.apples = new Apple[5]" because the length depends on json input and may not be 5?

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Unless the Enumerator returned by `JsonReader()` is iterated (perhaps inside `StartCoroutine()`?), the line `fruits = JsonUtility.FromJson<Fruits>(JsonText);` is never reached, and therefore, `fruits` is never initialized.

Comment: Put a breakpoint at the `fruits = ...` line and see if the debugger stops there (it probably won't). Otherwise, please try to create a [repro] and include it in the question.

Answer (score 1):

I am not entirely sure about that one. But I think the problem is, that Unity reaches the string apple too early because you starting a coroutine and while you creating the json object Unity is going on and tries to get a value, that is non existent yet. So what you can try is a custom event.

```
//Create a delegate and and event to fire at a certain point of time
public delegate void FruitsLoadedEvent FruitsLoadedEvent();
public static event FruitsLoadedEvent OnFruitsLoaded;

public void classSetup(){
    //Subscribe to the event
    OnFruitsLoaded += CreateApple;
    StartCoroutine(JsonReader());     
}

Ienumerator JsonReader(){
    .........unrelated codes hidden...............
    if (Url.Contains(":/") || Url.Contains("://") || Url.Contains(":///"))
    {
        UnityWebRequest www = UnityWebRequest.Get(Url);
        yield return www.SendWebRequest();
        JsonText = www.downloadHandler.text;
    }

    fruits = JsonUtility.FromJson<Fruits>(JsonText);
    //Invoke the event after checking, if anyone is subscribed
    OnFruitsLoaded?.Invoke();
}

private void CreateApple() {
    String appleName = fruits.apples[0].appleName;
}
```

I really hope that helps you!

Answer (score 0):

Starting a Coroutine **does not** delay the method that starts it itself. Wouldn't make sense if it would because you would lose the entire reason why making it a Coroutine.

What you would want to do instead is either move your code that shall be executed **after** the result is received into the routine like

```
public class MyClass : MonoBehaviour
{  
    public void classSetup()
    {
        StartCoroutine(JsonReader());     
    }

    IEnumerator JsonReader()
    {
       // .........unrelated codes hidden...............
       if (Url.Contains(":/") || Url.Contains("://") || Url.Contains(":///"))
       {
            UnityWebRequest www = UnityWebRequest.Get(Url);
            yield return www.SendWebRequest();
            JsonText = www.downloadHandler.text;
        }

        var fruits = JsonUtility.FromJson<Fruits>(JsonText);

        String appleName = fruits.apples[0].appleName;   -------> this is the line trigger the exception. 
        Debug.Log(appleName); 
   }
}
```

Or use a callback

```
public class MyClass : MonoBehaviour
{
    public void classSetup()
    {
        StartCoroutine(JsonReader(HandleResult));     

        // or the same as lambda expression
        //StartCoroutine(JsonReader(fruits => 
        //{
        //    String appleName = fruits.apples[0].appleName;   -------> this is the line trigger the exception. 
        //    Debug.Log(appleName); 
        //}));
    }

    IEnumerator JsonReader(Action<Fruits> onResult)
    {
       // .........unrelated codes hidden...............
       if (Url.Contains(":/") || Url.Contains("://") || Url.Contains(":///"))
       {
            UnityWebRequest www = UnityWebRequest.Get(Url);
            yield return www.SendWebRequest();
            JsonText = www.downloadHandler.text;
        }

        var fruits = JsonUtility.FromJson<Fruits>(JsonText);

        onResult?.Invoke(fruits);
   }

   private void HandleResult(Fruits fruits)
   {
       String appleName = fruits.apples[0].appleName;   -------> this is the line trigger the exception. 
       Debug.Log(appleName); 
   }
}
```